# Links in footer unclickable (bottom-fixed and behind content) when overflow-x is hidden for html and body

Tags: html, css, z-index, footer, sticky-footer

**Situation:**

Given the following simplified HTML example:

- put a footer *behind* content, make it *bottom-sticky*
- when scrolling to the end of page: footer shall unravel from behind content

I was able to do this but when I have `html` and `body` both set it's `overflow-x` property to `hidden` those links in the footer are not clickable.

**Update to situation:**

I know that it's possible to set z-indices for `#content` to 2 and for `footer` to 1 to make the links clickable, but that interferes with a multizoom.js from a different part of the page and is not of my interest.

**Question:**

What has setting `overflow-x` to both `html` and `body` to do with the links in the footer? And why must *both* elements set this property? (If just one of them omits `overflow-x` the links are clickable)

In fact for me it's no problem anymore not to set `overflow-x` in the originating project because it was a leftover from an outdated styling attempt and has been removed already. But I am curious why there's such a strange behaviour?

**Example:**

```css
/* This statement prevents the links in the footer
 * from being clickable */
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
/* necessary statements to put footer behind content and
 * make it bottom sticky behind content */
#content {
  /* opaque bg color to block out footer*/
  background: lightgrey;
  /* border bottom to see where content ends */
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  /* arbitrary height as content placeholder to provoke scrolling */
  height: 1500px;
  /* use margin to stretch the page in order for
   * footer to become visible at the end of scrolling */
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}
footer {
  /* bg color to distinguish footer from content */
  background: grey;
  /* make footer 120px high, centered */
  padding: 50px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  /* put footer one layer behind content so that content scrolls
   * before footer while footer itself is fixed at the bottom */
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  /* use all the width possible */
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  /* make page use the whole panel */
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        Here is the content, scroll down until end of page
    </div>
    <footer>
        <a href="#">Here is the footer link (not clickable at the moment)</a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you set your `#content` relative with `z-index: 2;` and footer `z-index: 1;`, everything works. Seems like body has a problem with `z-index: -1;`.

Comment: I know that it works with z-indexs 2 vs 1 (and I shall update the question) but that interferes with a multizoom-script (which would be a totally different problem)

Comment: @xmoex So `#content` shouldn't have z-index? Or is it `footer` that should have `z-index: -1;`?

Comment: @Green `#content` shouldn't have z-index. Btw: It's not about solving the problem in a different way, I'm interested why the problem was solved as it was (or what role overflow-x played)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see its about margin collapsing. Your `#content` has `margin-bottom: 120px` it produces blank space at the bottom, and `overflow: hidden;` produces new formatting context which allows body to be same height as `#content` block. `z-index: -1` pushes `footer` behind `body` in this case and you can't click link.

But when you remove `overflow` property, `body` will have smaller height than `#content` because of `margin-bottom` and `#footer` became outside of `body` and after that links become clickable.

Also note that `overflow` property on viewport does not clip fixed elements which are out of parent, that's why `#footer` remains visible and active.

Answer (score 1):

> What has setting overflow-x to both html and body to do with the links in the footer? And why must both elements set this property? (If just one of them omits overflow-x the links are clickable)
>
> In fact for me it's no problem anymore not to set overflow-x in the originating project because it was a leftover from an outdated styling attempt and has been removed already. But I am curious why there's such a strange behaviour?

As you said [it will work when you remove style from `html`](https://jsfiddle.net/pwf5n2q1/).

**Why do people style `html` tag?**

For now I have encountered at least three cases in which people style `html`.

1. When they want to set global properties values for the ones that
   inherits values from their ancestors.
2. When they want to force browser to display scrollbar.

   ```
   html, body {
       min-height: 100.1%;
   }
   ```
3. When they want to make table out of the page.

We can style `html` because it is DOM element which takes normal attributes ([W3 on `html`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-html-element)), but I, and as far as I know a lot of other people, strongly suggest to avoid using it, unless you want to do some cool tricks with it. Styling `html` may lead to unwanted behaviour due to the way browsers work. Keep in mind that `body` is not the only child of `html`. There is also `head`. When you want to style the visible part of your page you have got `body` for it (why would you style invisible part in first place?).

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the footer has a negative z-index and the body doesn't have any (so defaults to 0?). Putting **overflow-x: hidden** into the body's css statement extends the body over the footer (see *t1m0n*'s answer for the reason why).

Adding a lower z-index to the body and making it relatively positioned fixes the problem on Chrome, IE, Firefox and Edge.

```
body {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```css
/* This statement prevents the links in the footer
 * from being clickable */
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}
/* necessary statements to put footer behind content and
 * make it bottom sticky behind content */
#content {
  /* opaque bg color to block out footer*/
  background: lightgrey;
  /* border bottom to see where content ends */
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  /* arbitrary height as content placeholder to provoke scrolling */
  height: 1500px;
  /* use margin to stretch the page in order for
   * footer to become visible at the end of scrolling */
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}
footer {
  /* bg color to distinguish footer from content */
  background: grey;
  /* make footer 120px high, centered */
  padding: 50px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  /* put footer one layer behind content so that content scrolls
   * before footer while footer itself is fixed at the bottom */
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  /* use all the width possible */
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  /* make page use the whole panel */
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        Here is the content, scroll down until end of page
    </div>
    <footer>
        <a href="#">Here is the footer link (IS CLICKABLE NOW!!)</a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem with these changes to the css:

```
#content {
    ...
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

footer {
    ...
    z-index: 0;
}
```

**Explanation**

When setting `z-index: -1` for the `footer`, it places it BEHIND the `body`, making it unclickable.

We want it ABOVE the `body`, so we set its `z-index: 0` (or remove it altogether)

This means we also need to raise the content, so we set its `z-index: 1`

BUT - because the footer is fixed, it is displayed ABOVE anything that doesn't have a position properly set, so we need to set the `content`'s `position: relative`, to keep the perceived behavior.

Comment: The question was about the role of overflow-x: hidden set to html and body. A solution without this property set works perfectly fine even with z-index of footer set to -1

Comment: Well, I didn't change anything else so I guess the `overflow` settings are still in place